# Как переместить блок news__img на news__text,а news__text на news__img?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

```
$pc = new WP_Query('cat=10'); //категории постов которые нужно вывести?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>
     <?php while ($pc->have_posts()) : $pc->the_post();$count++; ?>
      <div class="news__post <?php if ($count % 2 == 0 ) echo ' two'; ?> ">
          <div class="news__img ">
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                      </div>
             <div class="news__text"><?php the_excerpt();?></div?
```

Answer (score 0):

Корректней задавайте вопрос, ничего не понятно, если отвечать просто то поменяйте местами блоки. Но скорее всего вам нужно поместить на изображение записи ее краткое описани, код ниже устанавливает на фон блока изображение записи, а поверх него выводит краткое описание.

```
 <div class="news__img" style="background-image: url(<?=get_the_post_thumbnail()?>);">
 <div class="news__text"><?php the_excerpt();?></div></div>
```